# Addition outside method inside class

Tags: java, class, methods, addition

This below operation providing errors while i'm adding outside of the method,

the below mentioned code declared as instance variable,and i performed addition inside the class and outside the method,

int a=10;
a=a+10;

if i add this inside method then there will be no compilation errors,why??

Comment: You are trying to add up outside of method?

Comment: If your question is why you cannot simply start writing instructions anywhere in the java class the answer is simple: because java wasn't designed that way and it doesn't make sense. When would you expect those lines of code to be executed and in what order?

Comment: In a class body you can only have: member definitions and initializer blocks. The only place to put statements is within method and constructor bodies and initializer blocks. `a = a+10` is a statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Java `int a=10; a=a+10;` is not possible. but you can try this, may be helpful for you.

```
public class AddOutsideMethod {

    private static int i = 10;
    private static int j = i + 10;
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(j);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Java, methods have the responsibility to perform operations on the instance variables. If an instance variable needs to be initialized, you can use constructor or initializer block.
You can do as below:

```
    int a = 0;
{
    a = a + 1;
}
```